# Python crashes when wxPython frames close - only on XP

Tags: python, wxpython

So I have a fairly involved set of wxPython frames that come up in my script. If necessary I'll post all the code, but I don't know that there's necessarily a code issue, because everything works absolutely perfectly on Windows 7. However, when I run it on Win XP, after closing the last frame (a print statement after the final Destroy() and Exit() statements runs, but nothing that happens in the program after) I get a 'pythonw.exe has encountered an error blah blah'. The error report prints a lot of information I don't know how to interpret, generally structured like "Module #... 'somedll.dll' *text*...".

I can provide all the code etc.. but was hoping there's just some basic portability requirement for wxpython in XP that someone can aware me on.

OK pasting a simplified code below. A few windows pop up in sequence, with the last one popping up repeatedly for a certain number of times. I haven't written code with this kind of nesting of frames before (or one that uses CallAfter()) so there could definitely be a problem with it.

```
import wx
GAME = 5

class Game:
        def __init__(self):
            "various attributes"

class UserFrame ( wx.Frame ):

        def __init__( self, parent, app):
            wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

            self.app = app

            self.m_button3 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCo, id = self.m_button3.GetId() )

        def OnCo( self, event ):
            self.Close()
            wx.CallAfter(self.nextFrame)
            self.app.Exit()

        def nextFrame(self):
            IntroFrame(None, app).Show()
            app.MainLoop()
            app.Exit()
            print "this prints"

        def __del__( self ):
            pass


class IntroFrame( wx.Frame ):
        def __init__( self, parent, app):
            wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

            self.app = app
            self.m_button4 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCo, id = self.m_button4.GetId() )

        def OnCo( self, event):
            self.app.myGame = Game()
            wx.CallAfter(self.playGame, self.app.myGame)
            self.Destroy()
            self.app.Exit()

        def playGame(self,myGame):
            apps = []
            for i in range(1,GAME+1):
                    apps.append(CustomApp())
                    PlayerChoice(None, apps[i-1], myGame).Show()
                    apps[i-1].MainLoop()
                    "simple decision tree for game"
                    apps[i-1].Exit()

        def __del__( self ):
            pass


class PlayerChoice( wx.Frame ):

        def __init__( self, parent, app, myGame ):
            self.app = app
            wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

            self.m_button1 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Choice 1", wx.Point( -1,-1 ), wx.DefaultSize, 0 )


            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCo1, id = self.m_button1.GetId() )


        def OnCo1(self,event):
            self.Close()

        def __del__( self ):
            pass


class CustomApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        self.myGame = None
        "some other attributes"


app = CustomApp()
UserFrame(None, app).Show()
app.MainLoop()
print "this doesn't print"
app.Exit()
```

Comment: I guess win XP overreacts on program close, you should maybe raise SystemError(0) on close to indicate the program closed correctly.

Comment: `print wx.GetTopLevelWindows()`  I bet you left a top level frame or dialog hangin around...

Comment: I printed GetTopLevelWindows where it seems to be having trouble and just got an empty set. No luck with SystemError(0) either.

Comment: You normally don't need to call Destroy() on the top level window unless you're catching EVT_CLOSE. I almost always use (and recommend) just calling the Frame's Close() method. We'll probably need a small runnable sample app to help you though.